# Right and fast way to test git directory and git branch?

Tags: shell, git, prompt, fish

While trying to set up my [new fish shell](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/) prompt, I ended up testing ways to get the branch name and also testing if I was on a git repository. I have found **(1)** `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`, **(2)** `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed 's/refs\/heads\///'` and **(3)** `git describe --contains --all HEAD` do the trick just fine.

I’m curious because I love the simplicity of **(1)**, but on a new and untouched (just `git init`ed) repository, it  gives me a “fatal:” error, while **(2)** works as intended, that is, giving me a default *master* as output. The thing is, even with a “fatal:” error, the return code is 0. Is that the intended behavior?

To test if I was in a git repository, I ended up simply testing if the current directory had a “.git” folder: `test -d ".git"`. Rudimentary solution, but it works, and it seems to be faster that using any git command.

So, my questions are:

1. Shouldn’t that “fatal:” with **(1)** return an exit code different from 0? If indeed it is a bug, since I don’t know how git people standardised their return codes, where should I report it?
2. I know if I redirect **(1)** with `^ /dev/null` (for those who don’t know, `^` is the same as `2>`), I won’t get the error, but it will say `HEAD` instead of master, but if I `cat .git/HEAD`, I get: `ref: refs/heads/master`. What should it really say? With `master` am I just being ignorant and picky, because it should instead say `HEAD`? I mean in the case of a just `git init`ed repository.
3. Have you actually benchmarked any possible solutions during your quest to get a nice prompt?

This is the code I use to benchmark (for fish):

```
set -l before (date +%s%N)
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
set -l after (date +%s%N)
set -l elapsed_time (expr $after - $before)
echo $elapsed_time
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: The tools are the latest GNU versions, I mean, `sed`, `date` and `expr`. I’m sorry if there is too much information or if something doesn’t make any sense. Bear with me. Thanks!

***EDIT:*** As someone correctly guessed in an answer, the whole error is:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Comment: Please post the `fatal:` error. Tough to know how it should be treated without being able to read it. :-)

Comment: I just did it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't fully answer your questions but probably a bit more than just a comment:

1. Based on other comments in your answer, I think the error you saw is `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` That occurs because you're conducting these tests on a brand new git repository, one that has no committed work. Not only is this not really a fair test (your performance will by definition be worse on a larger repository), it is in nearly every way an edge case. For example, `.git/HEAD` shows `ref: refs/heads/master` by convention. The error is thrown because `HEAD` is ambiguous. You have no history, thus any value passed to `rev-parse` would be treated the same. Additionally, this doesn't exit 0 for me:

   ```
   $ git init /tmp/test && cd /tmp/test
   $ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
   $ echo $?
   128
   ```

   In sum, don't sweat this error. Grab yourself one of the huge android repos, or perhaps the linux kernel, and test your prompt there.
2. `HEAD` is not a branch. It's a pointer to the checked-out state. When you've got a branch checked out, it's a symbolic reference to that branch. When you're in 'detached HEAD' state, the `HEAD` pointer is pointing at a commit. You get `HEAD` as the return using method (1) because `rev-parse` is just echoing the passed refspec value in the error. Try it with `blah`; you'll see the same thing.
3. I haven't actually benchmarked solutions, but a few things you might try (both are used in my zsh prompt, which I didn't write, and both have performed quite well):

   ```
   git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree ;# avoids your 'test -d .git' call
   ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) ;# grab the full refspec
   branch=$(echo ${ref#refs/heads/}) ;# extract the branch name
   ```

Comment: I’m not at home right now, but I’m going to try in my Android ROM source when I get back. Indeed what best place to try it out... Thanks!

Comment: --is-inside-work-tree is a much better option (but not as fast, though) than testing .git directory, since .git is only in the root. For the branch, “git help symbolic-ref” gave me the answer: git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null. Much cooler, a single command, perfect. No idea how I didn’t see it before. Thanks!